# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Limit viewing on database list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I have user1, he owns 3 db (db1 , db2, db3) and I want he can see only these 3 db when he login by using SSMS.

I did `REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM PUBLIC`, but then he cannot see any db in list.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure his server login exists.(Meaning you dont delete
   this!!!)
2. `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO user` (I think this is where you are stuck right now as the user is unable to view any databases.)
3. Then Delete his user logins from those 3 databases that he is a database owner on.
4. Then go to each database > right click > properties > files > Choose his login as the database owner on those 3.

This way he will remain the database owner on those db's and also not be able to view the other databases on that instance.

Tried and TESTED!!

Comment: Thank you very much, It works for me.
I want to ask one more things: user2 have login (db_owner) on db1. How can I make user2 can only see db1 when he logins by using SSMS ?
user1 still is chosen in "right click db1 > properties > files" as database owner.

Comment: Sounds good.Please mark it as answer if it resolved the issue.You cannot have multiple db_owners to one database!

Comment: You will not be able to hide the databases without having to make the user a db_owner! More information can be found here explaining this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935018/hide-sql-database-from-management-studio

Comment: Thanks, I think I can have multiple db_owner to one database by click database > Security > Users > right click a Login > Properties > add role membership as db_onwer ?
I read topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935018/hide-sql-database-from-management-studio , they conclude that it's complicated because "the permissions are stored at the database level, so it would require enumerating each database to determine if the user has connect rights to display the database in the object explorer, which is an expensive task to perform and how the older EM used to do things".

Comment: By the way your solution is enough for me now, I chose your answer as active but cannot vote it because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Sorry all,
I don't know if I should create a new topic or not.
I have SQL Server 2008 R2 with many databases & many users.
I want user1 & user2 can view db1 when they access by SSMS.
After
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO user1
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO user2
and assign user1 as db1 owner by database > right click > properties > files > Choose his login as the database owner
then user 1 can view db1 when access by SSMS but how about user2 ?